# Programmatically submit form using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit a form using JQuery. The form has no id, so I am trying to locate it based on its position in the dom tree:

```
$('form').eq(5).submit();
```

It is the 6th form on the page, so I am using the above code. The code runs, but I don't see anything happening. Is the page supposed to react the same way it would as if I had hit the Submit button that is intended to Submit the form?

Comment: pls provide me fiddle

Comment: Ok. So am I correct to expect that I should see some type of action on the page, similar to if I were to actually press the Submit button?

Comment: you can check on developer tools or firebug

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').eq(5).submit();
```

Make sure the code runs when the forms are on the page. You can look at it in a debugger or do a simple

```
alert($('form').length);
```

Comment: My mistake. form is not the actual id of the form, it has no id. Are you saying to look at it with firebug?

Comment: You can look at it in any JavaScript debugger. If you're unfamiliar with js debugging I would just temporarily add the alert I suggested. It should alert the number 6 if the forms are on the page.

Answer (score 0):

let this be the form,

```
<form id="my_form6" name="my_form6" action="">
```

you can submit it simply by:

```
$('#my_form6').submit();
```